# Communicating with Windows Process via RPC from a Java application

Tags: java, c++, windows, rpc, idl

I'm looking to communicate with a windows process via RPC. The application I want to communicate with is developed in C++ using Visual Studio 2008. The application provides its interface through an idl file which is then compiled using the microsoft midl tool. This application is already developed and cannot be modified.

I'm looking to communicate with this application from a second application that I'm developing in Java. Is the functionality provided by the windows application compatible with any Java implementation of RPC?

From what I've read on MSDN, the RPC provided by the Window application is DCE compliant. I haven't had any success finding details about DCE/RCP in Java, other than several articles that are 12+ years old and discuss the MS jvm.

I also had no success generating java code using the idl from the Windows application using idlj packaged with the jdk. The idlj compiler gives many errors about the structure and keywords in the idl file. I'm assuming because the MS idl format is incompatible with the one expected by idlj.

Does anyone have an experience with this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an open source java implementation ([Jarpac](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarapac/)):

From : http://blogs.cocoondev.org/michaelm/archives/002118.html